Given dm_db_missing_index_details output, what index(es) would support the following recommendations



FullyQualifiedObjectName
EqualityColumns
InEqualityColumns
IncludedColumns




table
[bool1], [bool2]
NULL
NULL


table
[bool1], [bool2]
NULL
[decimal1], [int1]


table
[bool1]
NULL
[int2], [int3]


table
[bool1], [bool2]
[decimal1]
[decimal2], [decimal3]



eg. CREATE INDEX [IX_table_bool1_bool2_decimal1_25233] ON [table] ([bool1, bool2,decimal1) include ??

Well it would be somewhat lengthy of an index, but including all of the columns in your include list (that aren't already in the main index list) would make the index fully covering for all of those scenarios.
E.g:
CREATE INDEX [IX_table_bool1_bool2_decimal1_25233]
ON [table] (bool1, bool2, decimal1)
INCLUDE (int1, int2, int3, decimal2, decimal3)

The downside of a lengthy index means more frequent writes will potentially occur since if any of those fields change, the index needs to be updated accordingly.
The upside in your particular case is most of the fields are in your INCLUDE list which then only stores them at the leaf level of the index, not within the entire tree itself. So that's less heavy, at least.

Thanks - that's along the lines of the concept of a plan I had. ;)

@MattEvans cheers, np!
